# Odoo 11 Web JS Framework doesn't initialize my module and thus doesn't register my client action

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11

I'm following the [Building Interface Extensions guide](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/web.html) with Odoo 11.

In the guide, it is stated that

> In Odoo web, modules are declared as functions set on the global odoo
>   variable. The function's name must be the same as the addon (in this
>   case oepetstore) so the framework can find it, and automatically
>   initialize it.

But my module isn't being initialized and I get the following error:

> Action error - Could not find client action 'petstore.homepage'.

I put some logging in the module and I found that the file is being fetched by the browser, as expected, but the initialization isn't happening.

This is my JS file:

```js
odoo.oepetstore = function(instance, local) {
    console.log('Started odoo.oepetstore'); ////////// [1] - This never runs
    
    local.HomePage = instance.Widget.extend({
        template: 'HomePageTemplate',
        start: function() {
            this.$el.append($('<div>').text('Hello dear Odoo user!'));
        }
    });
    
    instance.web.client_actions.add('petstore.homepage', 'instance.oepetstore.HomePage');
}
console.log('Loaded petstore.js'); ////////// [2] - This always runs
```

With Odoo 9 (after renaming the file `__manifest__.py` to `__openerp__.py` and renaming the variable `odoo` to `openerp`), everything works as expected.

Why isn't it working with Odoo 11?

---

**EDIT**

Here's my working code after following [Tchi-Odoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47030429/969249):

```js
odoo.define('PetStoreHomePage', function(require){
    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');

    var HomePageWidget = Widget.extend({
        template: 'HomePageTemplate',
        start: function() {
            this.$el.append($('<div>').text('Hello dear Odoo user!'));
        }
    });

    core.action_registry.add('petstore.homepage', HomePageWidget);
});
```

Comment: This is may be you forget to use actionmanager in your case. In the same doc of odoo official read para of "Actionmanager" and might you get your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in new version of odoo when you define a javascript module use this:

```js
              // key of your module so other require it.
  odoo.define('your_module_name.name_to_discript_functionality', function(require) {
    'use strict'
     // user require to load module that your module depends on them
     var web = require('web.code');
     // if someone need your module function he will load it by it's key 
     // var YouModule = require('your_module_name.name_to_discript_functionality');



    // if you define new class return them so other can use them
    return {
        NewClass : NewClass,
        ...
        ...
    }

  });
```